# Matplotlib: Increase figure height & plot spacing (is there a max fixsize?)

Tags: matplotlib

I have a matplotlib plot of >200 vertical bar charts.

```
# first line of code:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 100), dpi=150)
```

Despite setting the `figsize` to huge values, it does not apply the value and the chart gets crammed with overlapping rows:

[image]

I am using matplotlib 3.3.3 and Python 3.9.1. The issue occures both when executing the python script via command line and pyCharm.

I also tried exporting as PDF using `fig.savefig(pdfpath, bbox_inches='tight')` but it looks the same.

**What do I need to change? Is there a maximum figsize?**
**Does my screen resolution/size limit the max figsize?**

Edit: If I set `figsize` to even lager value, e.g. 4000 inches, then I run into
error "Fail to create pixmap with Tk_GetPixmap in TkImgPhotoInstanceSetSize"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that my **screen resolution** is actually limiting the figure size.

If I change the code secuence to **first plot and save as PDF, then show** the plot on screen, I get different results:

```
plt.plot()
fig.savefig(pdfpath, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]